# Is it legal to OWN a machete in New Jersey? (Decor purposes only)

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, civil-law, new-jersey, weapons

I bought a machete online about 2 hours ago because I thought it looked cool and I figured it would be nice to display it on my wall. I have no intentions to carry it, use it for illegal purposes, or even use it at all. I’m 16 incase that’s relevant.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to law.SE! Could you add some context to your question? In particular, what makes you suspect owning a machete could _not_ be legal? Generally, owning things is legal, so please edit to clarify why you think a machete would be different.

Comment: I figured since the laws for carrying weapons are so strict in NJ, that perhaps owning one would have the same consequences. They’re also very vague on what lawful and unlawful purposes are, there’s no mention on owning a weapon as decor or owning one for no purpose or intent to use it.